# Ajax is returning data from other source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have little problem with $.ajax in jquery. I am calling file response.php but i am getting response from index.php.

Files structure:

```
libs/response.php
js/main.js
...
index.php
```

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
...
<button id="bttClick">click</button>
...
</html>
```

Main.js

```
 $('#bttClick').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'libs/response.php',
            'type':'POST',
            'data': arr
         }).done(function(resp){
             alert(resp);
         });
 });
```

Response.php

```
<? 
echo "ECHO";
?>
```

Anyone can help? Thanks

**Answer:**
.htaccess

Comment: Add Slash "/" before libs means ('url': '/libs/response.php')

Comment: where are `index.php, main.js and response.php` located? the full path please

Comment: @user2899587 what is `arr` on ajax data ?

Comment: Even if add / also i think thats not any logical justify that the answer can serve from index.php?

Comment: @Arun read the question properly the path is mentioned

Comment: If possible post try to hit the response.php with other page ajax call

Comment: Path is good, it is relative path... i cant add slash

Comment: what is `arr` on ajax data ? if it is not useful then remove that

Comment: Anto King, i go to try it

Comment: arr is array of data examp...  var arr = { 'type': 'good' , 'id': 1 };

Comment: but in your code it is not declared `arr` data also check console for any errors

Comment: ok if you get post your answer

Comment: .htacces boys, thanks